# Global Structure with Dynamic allocation

Tags: declaration, structure

How to declare a global structure with dynamic allocation? All I know is via array structure but that is static.

Comment: Hint: You're going to use malloc for the dynamic part.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to dynamically allocate your structure in a function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct s *p;

int main(void)
{
    p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard practice is to declare the structure in the header file and define it in your function.

For ex:

```
struct node {
int data;
struct node* next;
};
```

This would be defined in the header file and will be allocated memory in the function dynamically like below

```
int main(void){
struct node *head;
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
//operations goes here
}
```

Also dont forget to `free` the structure after the use.